# Compodoc install Error in Angular 4

Tags: angular, documentation-generation, compodoc

I try to install compodoc for my Angular 4 Application 
https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc

my node version is : `v6.11.1`
npm version is `v3.10.10`
and Os is: Window `6.1.7601`
and angular/cli verion is `1.2.6`

I got this error while I install

```
Skipping optional dependency : fsevents@ 1.0.0
Skipping optional dependency : Unsupported platform
```

[image: screen capture of Error]

```
npm install -g @compodoc/compodoc
```

I try : any of these suggestion in [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13935) and still compodoc isn't install in my Angular application

Comment: the *warning* about `fsevents` is benign;  you aren't on a mac so you can't use `fsevents`.  If the module isn't functioning, it is because of something else.

Comment: yes, I on window and havent seen this error message while I install other node module.

Comment: again, **it's not an error, it's a warning**, because the package requires the optional dependency only when you are running on a Mac.

Comment: after that warning , when I run "npm run compodoc"
I got npm ERR! missing  script : compodoc